# Negation of Quantified Statements and Determine which one is true between the original statements and its negation

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

For each of the following statements, write the negation in such way that the "$\neg$" symbol is not needed, and then determine which one is true between the original statements and its negation.

1. $(\forall a \in \Bbb R)(\forall b \in \Bbb Z).(a^2+b \in \Bbb Z)$.
2. $(\exists y \in \Bbb R)(\forall x \in \Bbb R).(xy=x)$.
3. $(\forall x \in \Bbb Z)(\exists y \in \Bbb R).(x=2y)$.
4. $(\forall x \in \Bbb Z)(\exists y \in \Bbb R).(\frac{x}{y}=2)$.
5. $(\forall x \in \Bbb R)(\forall d \in \Bbb R^+)(\exists y \in \Bbb Q).(|x-y|<d)$.

**EDIT:**

**Attempt:**
Their negation is:

1. $(\exists a \in \Bbb R)(\exists b \in \Bbb Z).(a^2+b \notin \Bbb Z)$.
2. $(\forall y \in \Bbb R)(\exists x \in \Bbb R).(xy \ne x)$.
3. $(\exists x \in \Bbb Z)(\forall y \in \Bbb R).(x \ne 2y)$.
4. $(\exists x \in \Bbb Z)(\forall y \in \Bbb R).(\frac{x}{y} \ne 2)$.
5. $(\exists x \in \Bbb R)(\exists d \in \Bbb R^+)(\forall y \in \Bbb Q).(|x-y| \ge d)$.

The truth value:

1. The negation statement is true, since there is $a=\frac{1}{2} \in \Bbb R$ such that for any $b \in \Bbb Z$, we have $a^2+b \notin \Bbb Z$.
2. The original statement is true, since there is $y=1 \in \Bbb R$ such that for any $x \in \Bbb R$, we have $xy=x$.
3. The original statement is true, since for all $x \in \Bbb Z$, there is $y=\frac{x}{2} \in \Bbb R$ such that $x=2y$.
4. The negation is true, since there is $x=0 \in \Bbb Z$ such that for any $y \in \Bbb R, \frac{x}{y} \ne 2$.
5. The original statement is true: Notice that the inequality $|x-y|<d$ is equivalent to $x-d<y<x+d$.

- If both of $x$ and $d$ are rational, then so are $x-d$ and $x+d$.
  Clearly, there is a rational $y$ such that $x-d<y<x+d$, i.e. $|x-y|<d$.
- If $x$ is rational and $d$ is irrational, then both of $x-d$ and $x+d$ are irrational. Clearly, there is a rational number $y$ such that $x-d<y<x+d$, i.e., $|x-y|<d$.
- If $x$ is irrational and $d$ is rational, then both of $x-d$ and $x+d$ are irrational. Clearly, there is a rational number $y$ such that $x-d<y<x+d$, i.e., $|x-y|<d$.
- If both of $x$ and $d$ are irrational, then so are $x-d$ and $x+d$.
  Clearly, there is a rational number $y$ such that $x-d < y < x+d$, i.e., $|x-y|<d$.
  Thus, in any cases, we conclude that for all $x \in \Bbb R$ and for any $d \in \Bbb R^+$, there is a rational number $y$ such that $|x-y|<d$.

Any correction and helps would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Answers 1 and 2 are correct.

It is impossible for a statement and its negation to both be true (or both be false) at the same time, so from that alone, answers 3, 4 and 5 are already false. Let's see where you went wrong.

The negation of statement 3 is actually false. In your question, you argue that $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}(79\not=2y)$ is a true statement. The statement is actually false, because a real $y$ does indeed exist, such that $2\cdot y=79$, namely $y=79/2\in\mathbb{R}$.

The negation of statement 4 is actually true.

$\exists x \forall y(x/y\not=2)$

$\impliedby\forall y(0/y\not=2)$

$\iff0/0\not=2 \land \forall y(y\not=0\implies 0/y\not=2)$

$\iff0/0\not=2 \land \forall y(y\not=0\implies 0\not=2)$

$\iff0/0\not=2 \land \forall y(y\not=0\implies T)$

$\iff0/0\not=2 \land \forall y(T)$

$\iff0/0\not=2 \land T$

$\iff0/0\not=2$

It is indeed true that $2$ is not the same object as $0/0$. Consider this; the first object is an element of the real numbers, the second one is not. $0/0$ still "makes sense", if you will, just not in the domain of real numbers; as such, it can not be equal to any real number.

That said, I am unsure about the truth value of statement 5, because I don't have enough knowledge on the properties of rational and real numbers. That being said, it is still the case that between a statement and its negation, only ONE of the two can be false; the other must be true.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited my post. How about it?

Comment: Your answers 3 and 4 are now correct. Answer 5 "should" (intuitively speaking) be correct, but don't take my word on it! Also, you're welcome!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir. For 5, I used the Density of rational number in $\Bbb R$.